# How to replace PhoneWindowManager

Tags: android

Is it possible to replace com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager with my own implementation (actually I would like to make a small modification on the current one)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware......only if you take the Android source and build your own version then use it as your own ROM on a device.

However I haven't looked at leveraging the NDK where it may be possible